# how to get variables dynamically from .bpmn2 xml file in jbpm using java code

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

How Can i Get The Task-types and its Variables Dynamically from the .bpm  file using java Code in  bpm? Any condition is available or what is the procedure to access those things?

Comment: I need the task(node)types and variables  from my bpm n diagram in  kieworkbench(j bpm console) how can i get these using java from my bpmn2   file

Comment: when i completing my workflow(bpmn) diagram i will save my diagram .bpmn file so i need task(node)  types and variables dynamically from my bpmn file using java